# There is no pool defined on the current client - knex.js + node + postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am building an app in node.js and using the knex ORM. I am having trouble running my migrations - I keep getting the error:

`Error: There is no pool defined on the current client`

Here is my connection configuration:

```
module.exports = {
knex: require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: env.DB_HOST,
        user: env.DB_USER,
        password: env.DB_USER_PASSWORD,
        database: env.DB_NAME
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    },
    searchPath: env.DB_SEARCHPATH
  })
};
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking there's some kind of bug with PG and Pool2.. Can't find anything myself. But making the min Pool 0 might not help you either. Try removing the pool from there, and let that default.

Comment: I'd like to add, that the error you're having is a generic catch all for any error coming from PSQL. So there could be a "validation error" where two emails shouldn't be the same during an insert, and that would generate the same error. I was able to resolve my issue by logging the databases returns.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem among Knex users, most people mentioned they had typing errors in their configuration. If you haven't, can you check this discussion and see if any of the solutions apply to your situation? https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/823